# How to get single attribute Value of entity in Coredata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, row

I am having `Entity` Called `EY_Appliances` with Attributes `applianceId` ,`applianceName`,`watts`,`amountPerWatts`.Also i am Having Arrays like this:

Prefrence.h

```
#define APPLIANCENAME_ARRAY @[@"Fridge",@"Microwave",@"Mixie",@"Roti Maker",@"Coffee Machine",@"Dish Washer",@"Wet Grinder",@"Electric Stove",@"Ceiling Fan",@"TV",@"Table Fan",@"Tubelight",@"Bulb",@"AC",@"Vacuum Cleaner",@"CFL",@"LED",@"Washing Machine",@"Toaster",@"Room Heater",@"Iron",@"Motor",@"Water Heater",@"Inverter / UPS",@"Air Cooler",@"Steamer / Air Fryer",@"Hair Dryer",@"Laptop",@"PC",@"Tablet",@"Router / Modem",@"Home Theatre",@"Projector",@"PS3/PS4/XBOX"]

#define WATTS_ARRAY @[@"120",@"1000",@"700",@"30",@"167",@"810",@"180",@"150",@"75",@"120",@"75",@"40",@"60",@"1200",@"1400",@"20",@"6",@"300",@"1000",@"1600",@"1400",@"2400",@"1000",@"67",@"173",@"585",@"1026",@"15",@"150",@"4",@"4",@"17",@"240",@"10"]
```

DataAccessHandler.m

```
-(void)storeApplianceDetailsToEntity
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


for (int i=0; i<APPLIANCENAME_ARRAY.count; i++)
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EY_Appliances" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue: APPLIANCENAME_ARRAY[i] forKey:@"applianceId"];
    [object setValue: APPLIANCENAME_ARRAY[i] forKey:@"applianceName"];
    [object setValue: WATTS_ARRAY[i] forKey:@"watts"];
    [object setValue: WATTS_ARRAY[i] forKey:@"amountPerWatts"];
}

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Saving Failed with error %@", error);
}
NSLog(@"entityValue==>%@",context);

}


-(NSArray *) fetchApplianceDetailsFromEntity:(NSString *) entityName
{
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription;
NSArray *array;
fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];


array =   [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSLog(@"arr==>>%@",array);
return array;

}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
DataAccessHandler *dataAccess=[[DataAccessHandler alloc]init];
[dataAccess storeApplianceDetailsToEntity];
NSArray *applianceData = [dataAccess fetchApplianceDetailsFromEntity:@"EY_Appliances"];

//How to print the applianceName,If i write Like this applianceData.applianceName,it shows error…
}
```

1.How to print the applianceName?

2.How to set the applianceId primaryKey and store the value for applianceId 1 to 34?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary  *applianceData = [dataAccess fetchApplianceDetailsFromEntity:@"EY_Appliances"];
```

use keyword get back value

Answer (score 0):

`applianceData` is an array, so you need to access it through an index

Your code just now is using the appliance name as ID - if all you need is an identifier, you can use your index `i`

The load returns everything into the array - if you only want to load part of the dataset, you need to add a fetch predicate in `fetchApplianceDetailsFromEntity`

```
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(applianceId == %@)",idString]];
```

Comment: What is `idString`?Also while Storing itself i have to store applianceId value to `applianceId`.....You are saying it in fetch....

Comment: you haven't said anywhere what you want the ID to actually be - I assumed that if you had a value, you might store it in a variable called idString.   If you want to use the index, you just set that value in the store function instead of using the name

Comment: Am not able to set like this: `[object setValue: i forKey:@"applianceId"];`.Its not allowing i in setvalue:

Comment: is `applianceId` a string or an integer?  if it's a string you need to create a string version of your index first

Comment: Its `String`.How to create a string version of index.For Example,I have to store like Id1,Id2,etc..

Comment: I think you need to get some of the basics sorted out before getting stuck into CoreData!      
NSString *stringID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Id%d", i];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103845/discussion-between-raghunath-and-russell).